# Не могу найти файл

Tags: java, android, файлы

Есть приложение на *Android*. Я пытаюсь записать некий текст в файл. Имя файла я получаю так:

```
String filename = getFilesDir() + File.separator + "myfile.txt";
```

в итоге получаю такое значение для имени файла:

> /data/data/com.nm.myapp/files/myfile.txt

Данные в файл нормально пишутся. Однако я не могу найти этот файл на моем телефоне, когда пытаюсь открыть его каким-нибудь просмотрщиком текстовых файлов. У меня просто нет такой папки на устройстве: `/data/data`.

Пробовал найти файл с помощью разных файловых менеджеров, но не удалось этого сделать. При этом файл точно существует - я в него могу писать строки, метод `exists` возвращает `true`, кроме того, я могу из него читать  содержимое программно. Но когда мне нужно просто просмотреть этот файл, то не очень удобно каждый раз для этого читать его программно и смотреть в отладчике.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно найти и посмотреть этот неуловимый файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен либо root на смартфоне или используйте эмулятор, у него будет доступ.

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно, Android защищает данные вашего приложения от любопытных глаз. Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device может найдете решение.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь посмотреть содержимое, то создай файл в папке, к которой есть доступ.
Например:

```
File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android"+"myFile.txt");
```